# How to know who has opened the mail if more than one recipients in the , To filed of email , by tracking pixel image

Tags: c#, php, email

I have build a tracking system by pixel image , but I am unable to which email has been opened , if more than one recipients are in To or CC fields  .

this is my tracking pixel image :

```
<img src="http://xpn.com?pxl=787383-33ui3u3i3-11111 />
```

Please suggest how I can achieve.

Comment: a: reliably, you won't be able to, and b: I suspect you're getting downvoted mostly because this isn't a programming question really; perhaps also c: folks generally hate tracking pixels

Comment: Yep everybody hates being tracked...

Comment: also you are missing a double quote on you img src .

Answer (score 1):

You can't track an email send to multiple people, you will have to send each an email with a custom pixel with an id or hash to identify the user that you sent it.

```
<img src="https://trackingDomain.php?e=user@email.com" >
```

```
<?php

// please validate this, just as a request for demo purposes.
$email = $_REQUEST['e'];

// update database.
$query = "Update sentEmails set readed = 1 WHERE email = '$email' ";
//....
/// database logic etc.
//....
?>
```

Comment: I request you to please give any example of the url for what you suggesting .

Comment: Ok , but <img src="https://trackingDomain.php?e=user@email.com" > this be opened by all receiver as all receiver in the To field .

Comment: yep, all the people that read that email even if they fwd it.

Comment: so in this case , still will not be able to get who has opened . Suppose I have 2 recipients in the to filed ;abc@email.com and xyz@email.com and created two tracker img like ; <img src="https://trackingDomain.php?e=abc@email.com" > & <img src="https://trackingDomain.php?e=xyz@email.com" >. So in this case these two link  will  be opened  by both recipients , and still will not be able to know who as recipient  exactly  opened .if one recipient open and one not then we will never able to know . pls suggest

Comment: that's correct, you have to send 2 different emails. One to each email address.

Comment: but that would be separate mails .but i need all are in To fields .

Comment: @Rohit you can’t. What you’re asking for is impossible. You have to either send emails that only have 1 recipient, or not track WHO opened it. If the email has multiple recipients, the best you can determine is that the email was opened by someone. You have no way of knowing whether recipient A opened it twice, or if recipients A and B both opened it once. All you can tell is that two views occurred and possibly try to tie them together by IP, which is unreliable. And also, people generally hate being tracked.